# String comparison and sorting function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, filtering

I'm designing a guess word game and I need some help with one of the functions. 
The function receives 2 inputs and returns true or false.
The input my_word contains letters that were guessed and match to a certain word.
The input other_word is some word to compare with my_input. 
examples:

```
>>> match_with_gaps("te_ t", "tact")
False
>>> match_with_gaps("a_ _ le", "apple")
True
>>> match_with_gaps("_ pple", "apple")
True
>>> match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple")
False
```

My problem is applying it to return a False as in the last example and I'm not sure how to do it. This is what I have done so far. It works but not for a case when a one guessed letter in my_word appears 2 time in other_word. In this case I'm returning true but it should be False. 
The inputs must be the exactly in the format as in the example (space after underscore).

```
def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
    myWord = []
    otherWord = []
    myWord_noUnderLine = []
    for x in my_word:
        if x != " ": # remove spaces
            myWord.append(x)
    for x in myWord:
        if x != "_": # remove underscore
            myWord_noUnderLine.append(x)
    for y in other_word:
        otherWord.append(y)

    match = ( [i for i, j in zip(myWord, otherWord) if i == j] ) # zip together letter by letter to a set
    if len(match) == len(myWord_noUnderLine): # compare length with word with no underscore
        return True
    else:
        return False


my_word = "a_ ple"
other_word = "apple"

print(match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word))
```

Comment: Python 3. Thanks

Comment: FYI: You can easily chain replace instead of use the for loops. `sw = my_word.replace(' ').replace('_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "no space" version and a "no space, no underscore" version of your string and then compare each character to see if non underscore characters matched or if characters corresponding to an underscore have already been used. For example:

```
def match_with_gaps(match, guess):
    nospace = match.replace(' ', '')
    used = nospace.replace('_', '')
    for a, b in zip(nospace, guess):
        if (a != '_' and a != b) or (a == '_' and b in used):
            return False
    return True

print(match_with_gaps("te_ t", "tact"))
# False
print(match_with_gaps("a_ _ le", "apple"))
# True
print(match_with_gaps("_ pple", "apple"))
# True
print(match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple"))
# False
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need. I need it to return False in match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple")

Comment: @SHR - your comment got cut off. In which case above do you need it to return False where it is not?

Comment: >>> match_with_gaps("te_ t", "tact")
False
>>> match_with_gaps("a_ _ le", "apple")
True
>>> match_with_gaps("_ pple", "apple")
True
>>> match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple")
False

Comment: @SHR - based on your comment to the other answer, I think I am following you now. This is like hangman where any letters already used are off the table. See edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

This line here:

```
 if len(match) == len(myWord_noUnderLine)
```

Will not give you what you want right now.  In the "a_ ple" example, both the space and the "_" are removed, so your myWord_noUnderLine variable will be "aple", so checking for a length match will surely fail between "aple" and "apple"

Comment: No. The output for my_word = "a_ ple" and other_word = "apple" returns True because the letter 'p' is in both (you can run the code and see). In the can I need it to return Falsa.

Comment: Right, my bad, I thought it was checking something else I need to understand this better.  Could you elaborate more on why you want  your second comparison: `match_with_gaps("a_ _ le", "apple")`  to return true but the fourth one: `match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple")` to be false.  Why exactly should case 2 and case 4 return different outputs?

Comment: In case of match_with_gaps("a_ ple", "apple"), I need it to return False because if a user guessed the letter 'p', the algorithm populates that letter in all the places in the word. So in case of "a_ ple", the word "apple" cannot be a valid option because if the secret word was "apple" the user already completed the game.